# Twilio - How to send bulk sms with a different body text per phone number?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twilio

I have an average of 100 - 1500 phone numbers that I want to send SMS to. I want to include the person's name that is associated with each phone number in the body text. How would I be able to do this using Twilio?

```
client.notify.services(notifyServiceSid)
.notifications.create({
toBinding: JSON.stringify({
  binding_type: 'sms', address: process.env.NUMBER_ONE,
  binding_type: 'sms', address: process.env.NUMBER_TWO
}),
body: 'This should work!' //I want to dynamically change this per number.
})
.then(notification => console.log(notification.sid))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: `body: 'This should work!'` move this to variable `template` and generate `body` from `template` for every destination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways doing it.

An example:

file: `broadcast.js`

```
require('dotenv').config();

const twilio = require('twilio')(
  process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
);
const template = "Hello {name}, test message";

(async () { 
  const records = [
    {number: "+1234567890", name: "Someone Someonesky"},
    {number: "+1234567891", name: "NotSomeone Someonesky"},
    ...
  ];

  const chunkSize = 99; // let's not overflow concurrency limit: 100
  for (let i = 0, j = records.length; i < j; i += chunkSize) {
    await Promise.all(
      records
        .slice(i, i + chunkSize)
        .map(
          record => {
            const {number, name} = record;

            // copying template to variable
            const body = template.toString();

            // replacing placeholder {name} in template 
            // with name value from object 
            body = body.replace(/\{name\}/g, name);

            return twillio.messages.create({
              to: number,
              from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
              body
            });
          }
        )
    );
  }
})();
```

file: `.env`

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=some-sid
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=some-token 
TWILIO_NUMBER=+3333333
```

Install dependencies:

```
npm i --save twilio
npm i --save dotenv
```

Run:

```
node broadcast.js
```

Comment: I didn't know that Twilio would allow looping through that amount of phone numbers since they have the option to send in Bulk. I don't want my number to get considered as spam.

Comment: @user3111472 why You think that they will consider as a spam? Have You ever done like that and been abused? In fact You're paying for their service and You're sending message to masses which is usual case.
If You don't like that way, find broadcast API from twilio and pass template with placeholder fields.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Couple of things, Twilio will allow you to send multiple messages like this, but you should be aware that there is a limit of 100 concurrent API requests to the Twilio API. You might also find that carriers consider the messages spam if too many come from one number in a day. Check [the SMS guidelines for the country you are sending to](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/sms) to see if there's anything more you need to consider.

Comment: @philnash thank You for info. Great to know the limits. I've updated code to split records to chunks with size 99 (:

Comment: @num8er - Thanks for updating the code and when I read about the spamming issue that could happen. That was my concern. Also, thanks philnash for your comment too.

Comment: this is not notification anymore, the question is about notification SMS not simple sms.

Comment: @NomanJaved sorry, but question says to send bulk sms, why do You think it’s about notification? Are You author of this question?

Comment: I am not the author of this question, I were just looking for the solution of issue. the question has the code `client.notify.services` that indicates the sms notify therefore I thought it should have solution relevant to that.

Comment: @NomanJaved in previous comments I’m talking with user3111472 and we are discussing question of bulk sending sms. I really was thinking that You have forgot original account and now wrote comment. don’t think about my comment above as offensive.